# C# Style ComboBoxItem in code

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to set the FontWeight of a ComboBoxItem like so?

```
  comboCategory.Items.Add("foo");
  (comboCategory.Items[0] as ComboBoxItem).FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

Visual Studio likes this code, but at runtime i get a NullReferenceException.

Alternatively I could use this code, but I am looking for something smarter:

```
  ComboBoxItem temp = new ComboBoxItem();
  temp.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
  temp.Content = "foo";
  comboCategory.Items.Add(temp);
```

Comment: Well, I only have 4-5 ComboBoxItems where the FontWeight should be bold. So I don't really need to set my own DrawMode. 

Maybe somebody can explain, why my first code example throws that Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox's `Items.Add()` function accepts a type of `object` which in your first example is a `string` and then the line below you are trying to cast a `string` to a `ComboBoxItem`, hence your null reference exception.

If you want access to the font weight properties then you have to do something similar to your second suggestion in regards to creating your `ComboBoxItem` first and passing that into the `Add()` function.

You could potentially "simplify" your code like the following, but this is a matter of opinion whether this code is cleaner:

```
comboCategory.Items.Add(new ComboxBoxItem() {FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Content = "foo"});
```